# Get balance of usdc in web3modal button

Tags: vuejs3, web3js, nuxt3, ethers.js, web3modal

Can someone please help me with this issue, I'm using w3m-button  component and trying to have the balance show in USDC but it's not working, I followed the documentation and added tokens to createWeb3Modal, here's the code:

```
 const mainnet = {
  chainId: 80001,
  name: "Mumbai",
  currency: "MATIC",
  explorerUrl: "https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/",
  rpcUrl: "https://polygon-mumbai-bor-rpc.publicnode.com/",
};

const metadata = {
  
};

createWeb3Modal({
  ethersConfig: defaultConfig({ metadata }),
  chains: [mainnet],
  projectId,
  enableAnalytics: true,
  tokens: {
    80001: {
      address: '0x9999f7fea5938fd3b1e26a12c3f2fb024e194f97',
    },
  },

});
```